# Can I change the login email in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login

I created my Stack Overflow account using company email. When I leave this company, that email will no longer exist. So can I change the login email to my personal email? Because I don't want to loose my reputation.

Comment: I can't find a stackoverflow account on your profile

Comment: @DonaldDuck so you say I should not close questions? Sorry but it won't happen. You can also still submit the answer using the browser's dev tools, the server accepts answers to closed question for few hours.

Comment: @SagarV it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5662524/raushan-kumar), OP chose to hide MSE (possible SO too) so it's not showing as linked.